# For loop: save results of function in separate vector for each i

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe with two columns. One for mean, one for std. deviation.
I'd like to run a for loop and safe the results of

```
rnorm(1000,dataframe[i,1],dataframe[i,2])
```

in a vector with associated i in the name.

Like: vector_i, vector_i+1, vector_i+2.....

Any idea?

Comment: Which language? R?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. Yes its R

Comment: Yes. The best idea is to not do what you want to do. Sir the results in a list instead.

Comment: why not save the result into a list ?

Comment: matrix(rnorm(1000 * nrow(DF), DF[, 1], DF[, 2]), nrow = 1000, byrow = TRUE) not tested because on my phone.

Comment: Yes, matrix is more convenient I guess...
But still unsure, how to include the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if you want a matrix?

```
fun <- function`(mat,nb=1000)
{
     tt<- apply(mat, 1, function(x)
     {
         n<-rnorm(nb,x[,1],x[,2])
        return(n)
     })
 return(tt)
}
fun(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `mapply` which is an `*apply` functional that takes multiple arguments for the supplied function, applying values in corresponding positions to their argument. In this case, it will return a matrix where the columns are the `rnorm` samples.

Here is a simple example

```
#set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

myNorms <- mapply(function(x, mean, sd) rnorm(x, mean, sd), 500, 0:2, c(1, 1, 5))
head(myNorms, 5)
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -1.2070657  1.9847800 -4.026667
[2,]  0.2774292 -0.2247379  3.507334
[3,]  1.0844412  1.7097262 -5.695726
[4,] -2.3456977  0.8907800  5.176854
[5,]  0.4291247  2.7826079  5.514759
```

This will sample 500 elements from each distribution. normals with {mean 0, sd 1}, {mean 1, sd 1}, and {mean 2, sd 5}.

we can check the means

```
colMeans(myNorms)
[1] 0.001838821 0.944966777 2.158396474
```

and the standard deviations

```
apply(myNorms, 2, sd)
[1] 1.0348139 0.9585917 4.6880564
```

You would replace the final two arguments with the vectors from your data.frame.

---

Following up on roland's comment in the OP, it is possible to use `rnorm` alone without `mapply`as `r*` family of functions will take vector arguments for the mean (and sd where appropriate) arguments. But its usage may be a little different than expected. For the `mapply` example above, the function would be

```
set.seed(1234)
myNorms <- matrix(rnorm(500L * 3L,
                        mean=rep(0:2, each=500L), sd=rep(c(1, 1, 5), each=500L)),
                  500)
```

So the mean and sd of the desired distribution must be repeated for each random draw.

to check, we get the same means as above:

```
colMeans(myNorms)
[1] 0.001838821 0.944966777 2.158396474
```